# Code snippets after Sleep() method does not get executed

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, task, task-parallel-library

I am trying to understand tasks and parallelism in C#. I have the code below in console application. I was expecting the code after Sleep() method to run after 3 millisecond but the program exits.

Can anyone please provide insights to why it's not waiting for 3 milliseconds and complete the execution of the remaining code. How can I make remaining code get executed after 3 millisecond?

> ```
>     static void Main(string[] args)
>     {
>
>         Task task = new Task(() =>
>         {
>             Console.WriteLine("Task on thread {0} started.",
>             Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
>             Thread.Sleep(3000);
>             Console.WriteLine("Task on thread {0} finished.",
>             Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
>         });
>
>         task.Start();
>         Console.WriteLine("this is the main thread");
>
>        
>
>     }
> ```

[image]

Comment: Q: I was expecting the code after Sleep() method to run after 3 millisecond but the program exits.  A: The program exits because you didn't do anything to STOP it from exiting.  Personally, I'd recommend putting a [Console.ReadLine()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readline?view=net-5.0) after your final "Console.WriteLine()".  There are other alternatives, as well.  For example, you can call task.Wait() in your Main(): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.wait?view=net-5.0

Comment: The argument to `Sleep` is measured in milliseconds. `Sleep(3000)` will sleep for 3 seconds, not 3ms.  You are dispatching your background work to a thread pool thread (which is a "Background thread" and will not keep your app alive).  The way your program works is you start your app, dispatch work to a thread pool thread.  It starts, but then stops for 3 seconds.  Meanwhile, the foreground thread continues on and quits, ending the execution of your app before the Sleep ends.

Comment: As a side note, creating tasks with the `Task` constructor is frowned upon by the experts, unless you are doing something advanced that requires it. The common way of starting [delegate-based](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/03/a-tour-of-task-part-9-delegate-tasks.html) tasks is by using the `Task.Run` method.

Comment: Thank you @paulsm4 for providing insights into the code. I got why the code was not working as expected.

Comment: @Flydog57
 Thank you for providing insights. It was helpful.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, Thank you for the information, I will look into delegate-based tasks.

Comment: @sabin Tasks aren't threads, so it makes no sense to create a cold task and call `Start` on it. A task represents a *promise* that something complete in the future. When used to execute a method, the task won't run it by itself or create a new thread. It will pass the method to a TaskScheduler for execution. The default scheduler will pick a thread from a pool of threads.

Comment: @sabin even with a thread, nothing would stop the program from terminating unless you somehow waited for the thread to terminate. Your current code doesn't do that, so `Main` exits perhaps even before the task's code had a chance to run. Remember, a task isn't a thread. In a release build, the delegate may still be waiting to be scheduled when the application terminates. Use `await Task.Run()` instead. Or even `await task;`  or `task.Wait();` to force the application to wait for the task. With raw threads you'd have to use `Thread.Join` to wait before exiting

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thank you for the information. Things are getting more clear.

Answer (score 3):

Use `await Task.Delay(3000);` instead of `Thread.Sleep(3000);` (example below).

Please note the snippet below is a modified version of your original code snippet but with modifications for *demonstration*.

```
static async Task Main()
{
    await Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Task on thread {0} started.", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        await Task.Delay(3000);
        Console.WriteLine("Task on thread {0} finished.", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    });
    Console.WriteLine("this is the main thread");
}
```

**Note**: The above snippet is **only intended for exploring** `Tasks` thus **not to be used in a production environment**. Simply removing the usage of `Task` within question code snippet would be functionally equivalent, however this solution is meant to illustrate how `Task` *could* be used.

Comment: The await operator can be used only with in async lambda expression. This code will not be compiled without async.

Comment: Even after using async, the result is not as expected. It did not even print the line before Delay() method.

I am looking for insight as why its not executing the code after sleep(), in general it should just wait and execute the remaining code.

Thank you!!

Comment: @sabin I apologize, I hadn't validated your code snippet. I just updated the snippet within my answer. Please try the latest example snippet.

Comment: yes, your code works as expected. Thank you for your time and effort. I noticed that even the code I have run as expected sometime. When I run the application, in each run the output I get is different.

Run 1:
this is the main thread
Task on thread 4 started
Task on thread 4 finished
Run 2:
this is main thread
Run 3:
Task on thread 4 Started
this is the main thread
Run 4: 
this is the main thread
Task on thread 4 Started
sometime its printing main thread and then the one in the task and sometime its just opposite. sometime it prints all and sometime just main thread. confusing.

Comment: What's the point of awaiting a `Task.Run`? You could just remove that code and it would run the same.

Comment: @Enigmativity the first sentence of the question explains: _I am trying to understand tasks and parallelism in C#._.

Comment: @JesseJohnson - And do let me know how that helps with the explanation.

Comment: @Enigmativity - gives reason for your question _"What's the point of awaiting a `Task.Run`?"_. To learn, understand, and explore `Tasks`.

Comment: @sabin - I created a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4puCXR) which ensures `Task` being executed on multiple threads to further your understanding. *Note*: this is not production quality code rather a quickly thrown together example.

Comment: @JesseJohnson - There is no discussion in your answer about why you're using it. There's nothing instructive about it - other than it encourages someone to do the wrong thing. Please put some discussion around it's usage and why it shouldn't be used.

Comment: @Enigmativity - fair enough, thanks for the suggestion. Answer updated with disclaimer that intent is purely educational.

Answer (score 1):

you need to wait for the task to complete. And 3000 is equivalent to 3 seconds...it is not 3 milliseconds.

```
Task task = new Task(() =>
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("Task on thread {0} started.",
                Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
                System.Console.WriteLine("Task on thread {0} finished.",
                Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            });

            task.Start();
            
            System.Console.WriteLine("this is the main thread");
            task.Wait();
```

Comment: yes, you are right its 3 second but its not printing as you can see in output window

Thank you!!

Comment: @sabin code edited. You need to adjust task.wait() according to your requirement.

Comment: I couldn't find the article of @StephenCleary about handcrafting `Task`s. But it is not advisable to calling the Task ctor manually. The preferred way is either `Task.Run` or `Task.Factory.StartNew`.